# JavaScript "Module A" is imported by "Module B". B executes an A method A executes a call back to B and errors

Tags: javascript, import, module, scope

I have code in module A (Ajax Call) to do a Generic Ajax Call based on properties passed on Call.

Module B (Calling Ajax to get codes from database) imports the Ajax Module and calls the Module A Ajax with a property of B.CallBack to execute on success.

Issue is that Module A doesn't import Module B (an all others that may use it) and so when eval(B.CallBack(data)) B is not defined.

I want to do this as my Ajax function has a few standard function I would like to run for collection of statistics and handling major failures on network or database

Here is example code Module A (Ajax Call)

```
 export class Ajax {
    constructor() {
        this.url = "https://localhost:44381";
        this.id = 1;
    }
    static url;
    static id;
     call(properties) {
    
        let id = 1;
        
        $.ajax({
            type: properties.type ?? "Get",
            crossDomain: true,
            url: this.url + properties.url.trim(),
            data: properties.data != null ? properties.data(): {},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: properties.dataType ?? "json",
            xhrFields:
            {
                withCredentials: true,
                crossDomain: true
            },
                beforeSend: function () {
                    if (properties.beforeSend) {
                        properties.beforeSend()
                    }
                    Stats.start(id, properties.url)
                    $("navbar-icon").addClass('csa-icon-rotate').removeClass('csa-icon');
    
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    eval(properties.callBack + `(${JSON.stringify(response)})`);
                },
            failure: function (response) {
                    if (properties.failure) {
                        eval(properties.failure + `(${JSON.stringify(response)})`);
                    }
                },
            error: function (response) {
                    if (properties.error) {
                        eval(properties.error + `(${JSON.stringify(response)})`);
                     }
    
                },
                complete:function (){
                    Stats.end(id)
                    $("navbar-icon").addClass('csa-icon').removeClass('csa-icon-rotate');
                } 
    
        });
    }

}




(Module B) Calling module call ajax to get codes from database

   
   

 

import { Ajax } from "../../../helpers/dist/js/ajax.js";
    export class Code {
    
        constructor() {
           
        }
       
        static messages = function () {
            return {
                "allCode": {
                    "url": "/code/v1/all",
                    "callBack": "Code.populate",
                    "error": "Code.error",
                    "type": "Post",
                    "dataType": "json"
                }
            }
        }
    
        static get = function() {
            let ajax = new Ajax();
            try {
                ajax.call(this.messages().allCode);
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e)
            }
        }
    static populate = function (data) {
            alert('Called back');
        }
        static error = function (data) {
            alert("Error in Code");
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: i think question is a bit confusing, i am not sure where is module A and where is B and is Ajax module different from them or the same? and what is the error thrown and at which line?

Comment: Have altered it a bit.  A=Ajax B = Codes calling Ajax with callback

Comment: Ended putting te Ajax method in the app.js that basically imported everything anyway